# Working with Entity Framework solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: entity-framework

I just downloaded and built the now open-source Entity Framework.

My problem is opening the `EntityFramework.sln` in Visual Studio 2010. The projects seem to be only VS 2012 compatible.

Is there a way to open them in VS 2010? Maybe by tweaking the project files?

Comment: What open source project? If solution is on vs 12 is the point of EF to open it. If you want to work with EF in vs 2010 take another release, yes there are some new sugar since last summer when they had release for another fx branch, but main concepts you can find in releases that supports fx 4.0

Comment: The VS 2012 solutions are supposed to be compatible with VS 2010 - you should be able to just launch VS 2010 and do a `File > Open Solution` and then pick that solution file.

Comment: The solution opens but none of the projects are loaded.All show up with an 'incompatible' text in the project node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official answer from Microsoft on the [ADO.NET blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/07/19/entity-framework-and-open-source.aspx) -

> currently the EF6 projects and the source code are compatible with Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5 only. We are planning to make it possible to target .NET 4.0 and considering making it buildable from Visual Studio 2010 but we just haven't done the work yet.

Answer (score 0):

At

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/documentation

Scott Guthrie explicitly notes

> The easiest way to work with the code base is to install Visual Studio
>   2012 RC. You can also work with any other IDE provided you have **.NET
>   Framework 4.5** and **MSBuild** on your machine.

Comment: I do have .NET framework 4.5 installed but still the projects dont' load and show up as 'imcompatible' in the solution explorer